# TL494 duty cycle adjustment

Tags: pwm, duty-cycle, tl494

I'm building a simple pulse generator with a TL494 in single ended configuration.

My plan is to set the frequency between 20Hz to 1kHz and duty cycle between 0% to 45%.

I will adjust that with a potentiometer.

How can I adjust the duty cycle? I've tried by adjusting  PWM input, comparator or dtc. I test it with frequency below 100Hz and an LED at the output. I can see the blinking LED as a result, but I can't get a duty cycle between 0% to 45%. I just get about 0% to 100% and random duty cycle.

Please help me or show a circuit.

Edit:

Heres's the schematics I've tried:

[image]

[image]

[image]

At first (err amp sett) and second (comp sett), I got unstable up to 50% duty cycle.

With last schematic (dtc sett), I got a stable duty cycle, but it give zero to 100 percent not 50 percent, and also the LED stops blinking or stays  on at left or right edge of pot.

I also try to replace the IC, but still same.  When I replace it  with a KA7500, I got the expected result.

Sorry for my poor hand drawn schematic, I'm far from my home and computer at this moment.

Comment: Reverse pwm polarity to get 0-45% signal

Comment: Can you show your schematic please, I was confused cz trial and error.

Comment: in any case you score point for creative misuse of a 494… this is quite not the thing it was expected to do, you would have had a better experience with something like a 555 for that application. Anyway, as already commented we need a schematic to know how you tried to alter the duty cycle

Comment: @Lorenzo. Ok thats my schematics. With 555 we can't adjust duty cycle without affecting frequency. I need is independent frequency and duty cycle adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, resort to the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf), specifically page 8:

[image: datasheet]

As you can see, they tied all the inputs of the error amplifiers to ground, and then used the `DTC` and the `FEEDBACK` pins for testing, which is shown below, in the datasheet, as waveforms. However, as mentioned in the comments, it's a rather convoluted way of getting a PWM, unless you already had the chip at hand (or want to go further with the design) -- otherwise the classic comparator with ramp input would make a better choice.